# How to convert array to hash in Ruby using indices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-hash

I want to convert the array of this:

```
["Cyan", "Magenta", "Yellow", "Black"]
```

to hash like this:

```
{1 => "Cyan", 2 => "Magenta", 3 => "Yellow", 4 => "Black"}
```

How could I make it in Ruby language?

I've tried using this code

```
color = ["Cyan", "Magenta", "Yellow", "Black"]
var.each_with_object({}) do |color_hash| 
   color_hash 
end
```

But i've got error. What is the correct code for that?

Comment: "I've got error" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 2):

You on the right way and can combine [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) with [`Enumerator#with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) such way:

```rb
colors = %w[Cyan Magenta Yellow Black]

colors.each_with_object({}).with_index(1) { |(color, result), id| result[id] = color }
# => {1=>"Cyan", 2=>"Magenta", 3=>"Yellow", 4=>"Black"}
```

Since you tagged your question with [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), you can use [`Enumerable#index_by`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-index_by) (again with plain Ruby [`Enumerator#with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index))

```rb
colors = %w[Cyan Magenta Yellow Black]

colors.index_by.with_index(1) { |_, id| id }
# => {1=>"Cyan", 2=>"Magenta", 3=>"Yellow", 4=>"Black"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
["Cyan", "Magenta", "Yellow", "Black"].each_with_index.map {|e, i| [i+1, e] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = %w[Cyan Magenta Yellow Black]

p a.map.with_index(1) { |value, index| [index, value] }.to_h
```

Output

```
{1=>"Cyan", 2=>"Magenta", 3=>"Yellow", 4=>"Black"}
```

Another way

```
colors = %w[Cyan Magenta Yellow Black]
color_map = Hash[(1..colors.size).to_a.zip(colors)]
p color_map
```

Comment: or `a.each.with_index(1).to_h { |value, index| [index, value] }`

Comment: Ah! Yes, to_h accepts the block! thanks!

Comment: Integer doesn't have `zip` method, therefore this code will fail

Comment: @mechnicov I have corrected, I missed `to_a` method.